# React scroll nav

Tags: scroll, reactjs

I am looking for something similar like "jQuery One Page Nav" plugin.

(here is a sidebar and the menu items on it are activated when scrolling through content).

Is there a similar plugin developed by using React and not using jQuery? Was trying to find one, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-nav

code in this library helped me to implement what I want quite easily.